# How to understand "accidentally all objects" when in C++ loop?

Tags: c++

I watched the Cpp conf talk: [range for](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGu9XWsOgWQ#t=00m18s), and confused about the meaning of "`accidentally all objects`":
[image]
How to understand it?

Comment: Missing the word "copy" I guess.

Comment: Looks like he accidentally a word

Comment: @BaummitAugen: So his point is something() function is operating on the copy, not the original value, is it right?

Comment: It's a common joke based on what yuri said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slide should have said "accidentally copy all the objects".  You usually don't want to copy the objects into `v`, which is why Dietmar recommends making `v` a reference instead.